# Validating SSL certificate as soon as it is renewed

Tags: shell, unix, openssl, certificate, ssl-certificate

I have this piece of code to get the serial number once in a day and would like to compare today's serial number with yesterday's one to see if any changes and send email that Certificate renewed. And in real situation I have many remote host to check same and validate. Kindly share your thoughts and idea how can it be achieved.

Command :

echo | openssl s_client -servername unix.stackexchange.com -connect unix.stackexchange.com:443 2>/dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -serial